# Conditionally show columns.template in kendo ui grid

Tags: kendo-ui, grid, telerik

I am trying to only show this delete button based on a value called isPrimary. If isPrimary is true don't display it.

The question is how do I conditionally display the last based on a value from the model?

Here is the code I currently have.

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.GiIncidentReportList)
                  .Name("IRGrid")
                  .Columns(columns =>
                  {
                      columns.Bound(r => r.IncidentReport.IR_IncidentID)
                          .Template(@<text>@Html.Raw(@Html.ActionLink("[replacetext]", "Index", "ApprovalWorkflow",
              new { area = "Dailylog", id = item.IncidentReport.IR_IncidentID, createdBy = item.IncidentReport.IR_CreatedByLoginID, isPrimaryReport = isPrimary }, null).ToHtmlString().Replace("[replacetext]", "<img src=\"/Images/icon_edit.gif\" />"))  </text>)
            .Title("").Width(70);
                      columns.Bound(r => r.IncidentReport.IR_CaseNumber).Title("Case Number");
                      columns.Bound(r => r.IncidentCreatedByName).Title("Created By");
                      columns.Bound(r => r.IncidentCreatedDateTime).Title("Created Date");
                      columns.Bound(r => r.IncidentUpdatedByName).Title("Updated By");
                      columns.Bound(r => r.IncidentUpdatedDateTime).Title("Updated Date");

                      columns.Template(p => @Html.ActionLink("Delete","DeleteIncidentReport","IncidentReport",
                          new { incidentReportId = p.IncidentReport.IR_IncidentID, dlLogId = p.IncidentReport.DL_LogID, incidentType = p.IncidentReport.IT_IncidentType }, 
                          new { @class = "k-button k-button-icontext", onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this report?')" }).ToHtmlString()

                          );
                  }
                  )
            )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
columns.Template(p => @Html.ActionLink("Delete","DeleteIncidentReport","IncidentReport",
                          new { incidentReportId = p.IncidentReport.IR_IncidentID, dlLogId = p.IncidentReport.DL_LogID, incidentType = p.IncidentReport.IT_IncidentType }, 
                          new { @class = "k-button k-button-icontext", onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this report?')" }).ToHtmlString()

                          ).Visible(isPrimary == false);
```

Comment: That was close enough to get me thinking on a solution. Thanks.